# How to disable GoogleWebLight?

Tags: android, google-chrome, search, mobile-website, pagespeed

Out of the blue all my chrome links and Google search links started opening on GoogleWebLight, and I don't like it.

Not only will it allow Google to track me, but it also garbles page looks. I don't want it, and I can't seem to get rid of it.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Put this directive in your .htaccess file to prevent google and others from chewing up then spitting out your website in an undesired, disfunctional format:

Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot about this issue, actually, this is a good feature from Google for the slow connections, when the connection is slow the googleweblight optimize your search result and load the page faster than original website.

But the problem is when you use the googleweblighet it check the requested website SSL certificate and block the most websites which are not enough secure or the SSL provider is no known.

To disable the googleweblight follow these steps:

1. Open Google/Chrome and search something eg. "Stack overflow"
2. Scroll down and select the setting
3. In setting find the "optimize pages for faster loading" and select "Never" then scroll down and click "save".

See the image for more help.
[Goto setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukzSf.png)
[Select Never option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZjIb.png)

Comment: Not a good feature. Each time you load a weblight page, you have to load it again to see the info google stripped out. Then if you click a link to navigate to another page, and you decide to go back, you have to reload the weblight page to go back past it. The feature actually costs 3 times as much time and data for all who are forced to use it. Think about how much it costs google to develop this feature that only slows down the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit googls website and disable that option.
[image: You can disable in the settings]

Answer (score 0):

Go to: google.com/preferences > Select Optimize pages for faster loading > Select Never > Save.

Answer (score -3):

Try to compress your page size, Google weblight won't be appears in the light website. here is my trick [trick to disable Google Web Light](http://www.suaraguru.com/topic-106-disable-google-web-light-dengan-cara-meningkatkan-load-speed-cdn-page-1.html)